# Adding items to a database from a dialog

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a `spinner` in my `activity` that upon selection of one of it's options needs to handle the addition of a new object to my `Sqlite database`. the following solution works but everything in it looks like one big hack.
My layout:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spnMachineManufacturer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/et_params_width"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:prompt="@string/Select"/>
```

My activity code:

```
public class ManufacturerSelectionActivity extends Activity
{
    Spinner spnMachineManufacturer;

    List<Manufacturer> allManufacturers;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_manufacturer_selection);

        spnMachineManufacturer = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnMachineManufacturer);

        addItemsToManufacturersSpinner();
        addListenerToManufacturersSpinner();
    }

    private void addItemsToManufacturersSpinner()
    {
        final DbConnector db = new DbConnector(this);

        //populate list from db utility
        allManufacturers = db.getAllManufacturers();
        if (allManufacturers != null && allManufacturers.size() > 0)
        {
            //hack - create a manufacturer object for add new option
            Manufacturer addNewManufacturer = new Manufacturer();
            addNewManufacturer.setId(-1);
            addNewManufacturer.setName("Add new...");
            allManufacturers.add(addNewManufacturer);

            //add items to spinner
            final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Manufacturer>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, allManufacturers);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spnMachineManufacturer.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

    private void addListenerToManufacturersSpinner()
    {
        spnMachineManufacturer.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l)
            {
                Manufacturer m = (Manufacturer) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
                if (m != null)
                {
                    int size = adapterView.getCount();

                    //check if selected item is "add new..."
                    if (size == i + 1)
                    {
                        //create a dialog to receive the new manufacturer name
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        ManufacturerSelectionActivity.this);
                        builder.setTitle("Add a manufacturer");

                        // Set up the input
                        final EditText input = new EditText(ManufacturerSelectionActivity.this);

                        input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                        builder.setView(input);

                        // Set up the buttons
                        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                            {
                                String name = input.getText().toString();

                                final DbConnector db = new DbConnector(
                                ManufacturerSelectionActivity.this);

                                //Create a new manufacturer object
                                Manufacturer mnf = new Manufacturer();
                                mnf.setName(name);

                                //add the new manufacturer to the database
                                db.addManufacturer(mnf);

                                //refresh spinner
                                addItemsToManufacturersSpinner();
                            }
                        });
                        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                            {
                                //do nothing
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                        builder.show();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView)
            {
                //do nothing
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My concerns:

- The addition of a manufacturer object to my list of manufacturers
- The use of `ManufacturerSelectionActivity.this` as a `context`
- The creation of a new item in the database from within the dialog method (which is found inside a `setOnItemSelectedListener` method
- The call to `addItemsToManufacturersSpinner()` method from within the dialog method

Answer (score 2):

Your method `addListenerToManufacturersSpinner()` is very long. You are nesting two listeners here. It would be easier to read if you defined the listener first and then set it.

For example:

```
DialogInterface.OnClickListener myOnClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
    {
        String name = input.getText().toString();

        final DbConnector db = new DbConnector(
        ManufacturerSelectionActivity.this);

        //Create a new manufacturer object
        Manufacturer mnf = new Manufacturer();
        mnf.setName(name);

        //add the new manufacturer to the database
        db.addManufacturer(mnf);

        //refresh spinner
        addItemsToManufacturersSpinner();
    }
});
```

And then you can set:

```
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", myOnClickListener);
```

Another point is, that you should define string resources such as "OK" in your `res/values/strings.xml` and reference the string there. This makes your app more configurable and separates content from code.

Variable naming:

```
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l)
```

What do variables `i` and `l` do? It is good practie to use more descriptive names.